# PHP Cache not working when using Heroku with AFNetworking

Tags: php, ios, caching, heroku, afnetworking

I've built some simple `GET` webservice using PHP that return some JSON. I've tested on my local and cache is working perfectly fine. But when I deploy to Heroku, the cache simple doesn't work.

I made few tests, and the server is returning perfectly fine all the cache headers:

**Heroku** Headers response got from AFNetworking:

```
"Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=86400";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Sat, 20 Jun 2015 05:10:20 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Via = "1.1 vegur";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.10";
```

**Local** server headers from AFNetworking:

```
"Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=86400";
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Length" = 1711;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Sat, 20 Jun 2015 05:11:39 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=98";
Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.3";
```

Also, `NSCachedURLResponse` always return nill from my Heroku URL.

Does anyone have any ideia about this?

Btw: Using iOS 8.3 SDK.